# google Drive API exchange authorization code throws 500 at times

Tags: google-drive-api

Using this code to exchange the initial code of the requests coming from Drive UI with a token i can use to make API requests.

```
public GoogleCredential exchangeCode(String authorizationCode) throws CodeExchangeException {
        try {
            GoogleTokenResponse response = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, authorizationCode, REDIRECT_URI).execute();
            return new GoogleCredential.Builder().setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).setTransport(new NetHttpTransport()).setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory()).build().setFromTokenResponse(response);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("An error occurred: " + e);
            throw new CodeExchangeException(null);
        }
    }
```

In most cases it works, however in some cases (perhaps 5%), i get

```
An error occurred: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 500 Error processing OAuth 2 request
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error processing OAuth 2 request</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Error processing OAuth 2 request</H1>
<H2>Error 500</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: HTTP 500 errors are supposed to indicate a server side issue - not authorization or request format problems. FWIW, I see HTTP 500 responses on occasion for "www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files" via com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$List.execute:
 `500 Internal Server Error
 {
   "code" : 500,
   "errors" : [ {
     "domain" : "global",
     "message" : "Internal Error",
     "reason" : "internalError"
   } ],
   "message" : "Internal Error"
 }`

Comment: Thanks for confirming my fears, @BradTofel. The problem is there nonetheless and i can't convince users that this is not my code's fault... Should i be introducing a retrial mechanism? As far as i remember such a code can only be exchanged once so not sure if that would work.

Comment: The code can only by *successfully* exchanged once. Since you got a `500`, you should be safe to retry; if indeed, the code can't be re-exchanged, you would get another status code such as `400`. Worst case scenario, you would have to redirect the user to the authorization page again.

Comment: Alain, any comment on whether making this "retry on 500" a part of the default API, at least in some cases? Seems like an easy way to improve perceived service stability, save headaches and duplicate code, and help enforce a recommended retry policy (like exponential back off, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I get '500 Internal Server Errors' to approx. 0.5% of my API calls. I have a retry mechanism which always seems to succeed on the second attempt.

```
    function doSomething(req) {
.
.
.
.
         restRequest.execute(function(resp) {
    var myResp = new Object();

    try {
        if (resp.error) {
            if (resp.error.code == "401") {
                do401(function() {
                    doSomething(req);
                }, req, myResp);
                return;
            }
            if (resp.error.code == "403") {
                cl("403 no auth " + resp.error.message);
                return;
            }
            if (resp.error.code == "500") {
                cl("server error 500, retrying " + resp.error.message);
                exponentialBackoff();
                                    doSomething(req);
                return;
            }
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        cl("[fg62] exception " + ex);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This is along the lines of what i tried too. Then found this helping thread...

[https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oauth2-dev/J5_dlPPkHl0%5B1-25%5D](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oauth2-dev/J5_dlPPkHl0%5B1-25%5D)

Apparently it is certain that if this error occurs, after 70 seconds i will definitely get a good exchange using the same token. In the meantime the user can watch a movie or something. 

As a paranthesis, i implemented retrial with exponential backoff, but sometimes even after 5 retries (!!!) i get the same error. Other times works in few retries.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a timeout between 2 of our internal servers during the authorization process (auth code exchange of the OAuth 2.0 server side flow). We were facing the same issue with the OAuth 2.0 Playground. This should have now been resolved by the auth team at Google.
Let us know if you get this issue again.

A retry mechanism is usually good to workaround transient 503 errors that you get from the Drive API. But in that case (500 errors from the Auth servers) it wasn't helping because the same call would time out every time for the same users in the same server configuration (i.e. users and server in distant geo regions).